# What MnO2 and graphite do I need for making a dry cell battery?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, electrochemistry

I'm playing around with making my own dry-cell battery and I want to make sure I understand the pieces before diving into it.

My plan is to make it like a layer cake: zinc sheet, paste of electrolyte, layer of $\ce{MnO2}$ powder, graphite sheet, and a metal sheet with a wire connected to it.

What I'd like to understand better is:

1. Could I replace the zinc sheet with Zn powder? (Also [this is interesting](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/356/6336/415.full), but I don't understand what's meant by a Zn sponge, is it Zn powder with $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$?)
2. How pure/fine does the $\ce{MnO2}$ powder need to be? Potters used $\ce{MnO2}$ to color clay, is [this the same stuff as what's in batteries](http://www.theceramicshop.com/product/9870/Manganese-Dioxide-20x40/)?  I tried emailing a few places but they didn't know the chemical properties and I'm not confident enough to go for it without double checking first :/
3. Could I use [carbon filters](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Broan-43000-Series-Non-Ducted-Charcoal-Filters-for-Range-Hood-3-each-SR610051/100600325?cm_mmc=Shopping%7cG%7cBase%7cD29A%7c29-15_COOKING%7cMULTI%7cNA&gclid=Cj0KCQjw6J7YBRC4ARIsAJMXXsdOPtSTbH4K9y1kwLHrBFZkL8CaQZu5qI2ETWgc2iJ-THbQX2wKG5waAtvTEALw_wcB&dclid=CISrjLjrodsCFYioyAodd-gCjw) or even crushed charcoal or does the electrode need to be a solid sheet of graphite?  I think carbon filters and graphite sheets have the same chemical properties, but I'm not sure.